# when I use Sort Filter Proxy Model to search File System Model it reset to root directory, my computer and show all the drives

Tags: python, qt, search, pyside, maya

when I use `QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()` to search `QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()` it reset to root directory
it happen in this line: `self.mainListViewProxyModel.setFilterWildcard("*{}*".format(text))`

```
        ### listViewStart
        
        self.mainListViewModel = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
        self.mainListViewModel.setRootPath('')  
        self.mainListViewModel.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QtCore.QDir.AllEntries | QtCore.QDir.Dirs | QtCore.QDir.Files)    

        self.mainListViewProxyModel = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.mainListViewProxyModel.setSourceModel(self.mainListViewModel)
        self.mainListViewProxyModel.setFilterRegularExpression(r'^(.*\.ma|.*\.fbx|.*\.mb|.*\.obj|[^.]+)(?!.*\.mayaSwatches$)$') 

        
        self.mainListView = QtWidgets.QListView()
        self.mainListView.setModel(self.mainListViewProxyModel)
        self.mainListView.setRootIndex(self.mainListViewProxyModel.mapFromSource(self.mainListViewModel.index(r'D:\reza_niroumand\Script\asset_browser\Examples')))
        
        self.mainListView.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
        self.mainListView.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.IconMode)
        self.mainListView.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Adjust)
        self.mainListView.setMovement(QtWidgets.QListView.Static)
        list_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        list_layout.addWidget(self.mainListView)
        self.hard_pinkFrame.setLayout(list_layout)
        
        
        self.list_icon.clicked.connect(self.change_view)        
        
        
        ### listViewEnd   
    def update_main_list_view(self, index):
        # Get the selected item's path from the tree view
        selected_index = self.treeViewProxyModel.mapToSource(index)
        self.path = self.treeViewModel.filePath(selected_index)

        # Set the root index of the list view to the selected item's path
        self.mainListView.setRootIndex(self.mainListViewProxyModel.mapFromSource(self.mainListViewModel.index(self.path)))
       
    def filter_list_view(self):
        text = self.search.text()       
        self.mainListViewProxyModel.setFilterWildcard("*{}*".format(text))
```

how can I search `listview` without resetting my `listview`.